# Given an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ and a vector, $v$ such that $M^nv = 0$ and $v,Mv,\ldots,M^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent, show that $M^n = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and $v$ a vector such that $M^n v = 0$. Show that if $v,Mv,\ldots,M^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent, then $M^n$ = 0.

It's easy to prove that $v,Mv,\ldots,M^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent (given $Mv,\ldots,M^n-1v \neq 0$ and $Mv = 0$), but I can't find a way of proving the statement above. Can't even begin to compose an argument. Could anyone provide some hints?

Comment: Cayley–Hamilton theorem

Comment: As $v,\ldots,M^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent, they form a basis.

Comment: You can write $M^n$ as linear combination of $M^{n-1}, \ldots, M, I$

Comment: Note that the subspace $V$ of $K^n$ generated by the $M^pv$, $0 \leq p < n$ has dimension $n$ and is contained in the kernel of $M^n$. But $n=\dim{K^n}$, so that $V=K^n$ and $M^n$ vanishes on $K^n$ so that $M^n=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathcal{B} = \left\lbrace M^{n-1}v,\cdots Mv,v \right\rbrace$ are linearly independant, they form a basis of  $V$ in which the associated matrix results to be $$M_{\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{B}}(f) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0  &\cdots & 0  & \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & \cdots & \cdots &\ddots & 0 \\ \vdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & 1 \\ 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

You can easily check that $M^{n} = 0$ since the power of $M$ "shift" the upper diagonal each time a diagonal above.

Comment: Where $V$ is the space spanned by $M^n$? If so, how do you know that $\{v,Mv,\ldots,M^{n-1}v\}$ spans V?

Comment: @Rodrigo You said you prove they are linear independant quite easily, since the dimension is $n$ they also generate, hence they are a basis, so they span $V$.

Comment: Yes, I know that they're going to generate a space. My questions is how do you know that they're going to generate specifically the same space as $M^n$?

Answer (score 2):

All of $v, Mv, \ldots , M^{n-1}v$ are in the kernel of $M^n.$ If they are linearly independent, those vectors also span the whole space. The kernel of $M^n$ being the whole space implies $M^n=0.$

Comment: How do you know that $v,Mv, \ldots, M^{n-1}v$ spans the same space as $M^n$?

Comment: $M$ is a square matrix of dimension $n$, so the vector space that $M$ (and $M^n$) acts on is $n$ dimensional. On the other hand, the $n$ linearly independent vectors you mention spans an $n$ dimensional space as well. It is an elementary result that any $n$ dimensional subspace of an $n$ dimensional space must be the entire space itself.

Comment: I see. Wasn't making the connection that $v,Mv, \ldots,M^{n-1}v$ was a subspace of $M^n$.